# When is the CKEDITOR script loaded and ready to use?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

Is there a better way of figuring out when CKEDITOR is loaded and certain functionality is available? I've included below the code that we're currently using, but it relies on setTimeouts and counters to check every so often if CKEDITOR is ready. Sometimes the code gets to the first if statement and CKEDITOR is available (not null) but the event handling has not loaded, so CKEDITOR.on is not a function. I'm essentially looking for a solution that relies on event handling (perhaps an event that CKEDITOR fires when it is ready?) instead of setTimeouts.

**TL;DR: CKEDITOR.on is not yet available as a function**

Only certain pages require CKEDITOR so it is being loaded on demand depending on the page's content.

VERSION: Using CKEDITOR 4.8

```
  Main.Script.getScript(javascript('external/ckeditor/ckeditor.js'), function() {
    var count = 0,
        init = function() {
          count++;
          if (CKEDITOR && CKEDITOR.on) {
            /*
              According to https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_editor.html#event-loaded,
              the "loaded" event is fired when editor components (configuration, languages, and plugins)
              are fully loaded and initialized.
             */
            CKEDITOR.on('loaded', function() {
              // Trigger _ckeditorReady event for custom event handling (CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady'), etc.)
              $(window).trigger('_ckeditorReady');
            });
          } else {
            if (count < 50) {
              $(script).ready(function() {
                setTimeout(init, 20);
              });
            }
          }
        };
    $(script).ready(function() {
      setTimeout(init, 20);
    });
  });
```

Comment: An event trigger would be the sane approach. I don't know enough about CKEditor to say whether such an event exists. But even barring that, it seems like using `setInterval`, perhaps with a `try` / `catch` block, would be a cleaner approach here than using `setTimeout`.

Answer (score -2):

there is [`instanceReady`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_editor.html#event-instanceReady) event, which is fired when editor is loaded and ready for interaction.
Example how to use it:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
  on: {
    'instanceReady': function( evt ) {
      var editor = evt.editor;
      console.log( 'Hello world' );
      console.log( JSON.stringify( CKEDITOR.tools.objectKeys( editor.plugins ) ) );
    }
  }
} );
```

Another way to implement this same event:

```
var myeditor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor' );

myeditor.on( 'instanceReady', function( evt ) {
  var editor = evt.editor;
      console.log( 'Hello world' );
      console.log( JSON.stringify( CKEDITOR.tools.objectKeys( editor.plugins ) ) );
} );
```

Source: https://codepen.io/msamsel/pen/LQBLxw?editors=1111

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, but this does not answer the question. As detailed above, CKEDITOR.on is not yet available as a function (the script is not done loading), so I cannot use it. I'm trying to find a solution that will let me know when CKEDITOR.on is even available.

Comment: @JuliaNething it does answer the question, you just need to fix your dynamic loading.